# syntactic analysis of a phrase with FROM...TO

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns, complex-sentences, complements

In the sentence

> Everything we do, from eating and ice cream to crossing the Atlantic and from baking a loaf to writing a novel, involves the use of coal, directly or indirectly.

I can't come up with the answer to the syntactic function of the two phrases *from eating an ice cream to crossing the Atlantic* and *from baking a loaf to writing a novel*. Are these adjuncts complementing the verb *do*? Are these complements to the pronoun *everything*?

Comment: Yes, they are adjuncts, more specifically supplementary adjuncts - that's their function. Categorywise, in simple terms they are a coordination of two paired preposition phrases.

Comment: They are complementing the noun phrase *everything we do*. HTH.

Comment: I take them not as complements, but adjuncts. Notice that the coordination is an interpolation, set apart from the main part of the sentence intonationally and by punctuation - usually a sure sign of supplementation